# Passing Hashmap as parameter in EJB3 WebService

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, ejb-3.0

I have exposed an api of EJB3 bean as a WebService and it takes HashMap of java as a parameter but while getting value in WebService Bean from hashMap I am getting null value.

```
@EJB(mappedName = "ODBillGenerationSession",name = "ODBillGenerationSession")
IODBillGenerationSessionRemoteHome iodBillGenerationSessionRemoteHome = null;
IODBillGenerationSessionRemote iodBillGenerationSessionRemote = null; 
public String echo(@WebParam(name="hashMap") HashMap hashMap) {
    return "Hello "+hashMap.get("name");
}
```

My request XML which I am executing from SOAP UI is below:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://interfaces.billingengine.ws.billingengine.elitecore.com/"> <soapenv:Header/>    <soapenv:Body>
      <int:echo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>Test</arg0>
      </int:echo>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the same web service is working fine when I am passing java String object.

I think I am missing some annotation here which I searched but not found.

```
<definitions name="ODBillGenerationWsSessionFacadeService" targetNamespace="http://session.billingengine.ws.billingengine.elitecore.com/">
<import location="http://10.105.1.6:8180/odbillgeneration-ws/ODBillGenerationWsSessionFacade?wsdl&resource=IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote_PortType6834015600007002099.wsdl" namespace="http://interfaces.billingengine.ws.billingengine.elitecore.com/"/>
    <service name="ODBillGenerationWsSessionFacadeService">
        <port binding="ns1:IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemoteBinding" name="ODBillGenerationWsSessionFacadePort">
            <soap:address location="http://10.105.1.6:8180/odbillgeneration-ws/ODBillGenerationWsSessionFacade"/>
        </port>
    </service>
```

Correct WSDL

```
<definitions name="ODBillGenerationWsSessionFacadeService" targetNamespace="http://interfaces.billingengine.ws.billingengine.elitecore.com/">
    <types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://interfaces.billingengine.ws.billingengine.elitecore.com/" version="1.0">
            <xs:element name="echo" type="tns:echo"/>
            <xs:element name="echoResponse" type="tns:echoResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="echo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="tns:hashMap"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="hashMap">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="tns:abstractMap">
                        <xs:sequence/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="abstractMap">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="echoResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote_echoResponse">
        <part element="ns1:echoResponse" name="echoResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote_echo">
        <part element="ns1:echo" name="echo"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote">
        <operation name="echo" parameterOrder="echo">
            <input message="ns1:IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote_echo"/>
            <output message="ns1:IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote_echoResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemoteBinding" type="ns1:IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="echo">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
</definitions>
```

Comment: @Milijen :- Have pasted the WSDL but it is not created manually it is generated by JBOSS 5.

Comment: Is there some external XSD or something that contains definitions? I would like to see the mapping of your "hashMap" input parameter.

Comment: No there is no external XSD or something that contains definitions. I've used the annotations mentioned in the above code snippet where I have mentioned the api echo details.

Comment: OK, but annotations are in the end mapped into some kind of configuration. How can external client know what kind of parameter to send to your Web method?

Comment: I can see you're importing IODBillGenerationWsSessionRemote_PortType6834015600007002099.wsdl and ODBillGenerationWsSessionFacade.wsdl, they might contain required definitions.

Comment: @Milijen : Thanks but when I use SOAP UI for testing than also the value is null.

Comment: Yes, because probably you don't send appropriate key-value pair. I can see from your request that you're only sending "arg0" with value Test, there's no key "name" that you're looking for in your Web service method.

Comment: @Milijen : Thanks for pointing my mistake I'll have also tried in this way <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://interfaces.billingengine.ws.billingengine.elitecore.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <int:echo>
         <arg0>
           <key>name</key>
           <value>test</value>
         </arg0>
      </int:echo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> but still the value is null can you point me out the correct request xml. Thanks in ADVANCE.

Comment: I have responded in a separate answer, so please check and comment/accept/whatever there.

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending key-value pair, so your Web method cannot read required key "name". Replace your SOAP body with this one:

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <int:echo>
         <hashMap>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <arg0>
               <key>name</key>
               <value>someValue</value>
            </arg0>
         </hashMap>
      </int:echo>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Also, change the type of input parameter from `HashMap` to `HashMap<String,String>`. That should do the trick.

Comment: @Milijen : Thanks but still not working... Compulsory have to use <arg0> tag else giving NullPointerException.

Comment: I have updated the answer, try to change the type of parameter in Web method and try again.

Comment: @Milijen : Thanks for the efforts. But still the value is null.

Comment: Can you expose the service and post the URL? I would like to try it see where's the problem.

Comment: Please also add the Metro version (or at least application server version) where you run your Web service.

Comment: @Milijen :- I am using Jboss 5.1.2 version.

Comment: I am using Glassfish but it also generates a kind of weird WSDL which SoapUI cannot recognize properly. Please generate it with your IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse or whatever you're using) and pass that to SoapUI. That's how it worked for me.

Comment: Key is in Metro version, if you have newer version it will generate proper WSDL. Look what I got on my Glassfish with old Metro (e.g. v1.x):<xs:complexType name="echo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="tns:hashMap" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="hashMap">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:abstractMap">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="abstractMap" abstract="true">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>

Comment: And new Glassfish (v3.1.2.2) with newer Metro (v2.2): <xs:complexType name="echo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

Comment: The latter will go smoothly with SoapUI, the former will cause that SoapUI generates incorrect SOAP request, like the one you pasted in your question.